# My visa application was refused because of the previous frequent travels to the UK with a 6 months tourist visa

Tags: visa-refusals, russian-citizens, deception

So my case seems to be quite complicated.

I'm from Russia, currently living in Russia, studying at University there with a programme that allows me to attend only exams sessions and to study from home most of the time.

I have an Italian boyfriend who lives and has a permanent job in London, UK. We've been together for 2.5 years.

In December 2016 I got a 6 months UK tourist visa, with a purpose of attending a 2 weeks English course. After I attended  the course, I came back to Russia, but then went back to the UK quite a few times more, usually staying for about 2 weeks. When I applied for that first visa, the agency that helped me with the documents told me that it's better to state that I don't have any friends and family members living there.

After the visa expired I applied for a new tourist visa, and my application was refused. In the explanation letter they wrote that they don't find it credible that I don't have any friends/family members in the UK and that I do really study in Russia whilst travelling abroad so often.

After that I tried to consult with a few other agencies based in the UK to help me to get the visa, and they all proposed to attach an invitation and a sponsorship letter from my boyfriend this time, saying that it would help me even to get a multiple entry visitor visa for 2 years. But in one of the agencies they asked me for more details and it was the first time that I mentioned stating that I don't have any friends or family members in the UK, on which they replied that the fact that I gave false information in my applications before can cause big problems such as being banned from the UK for 10 years.

Could somebody please advise me possible options in this situation? I want to visit my boyfriend on the regular basis, but it seems like I can't mention him now in my new application, and I also can't apply for a new visa without any changes in the circumstances that I state in my application.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you ever lived with your boyfriend?  If so, for how long?  Could you marry him?

Comment: I haven't lived with my boyfriend. I mean when I was coming to the UK I usually stayed for about 2 weeks, and then was coming back to Russia also for 2 weeks. So half of our time we spent together. Getting married was not in our plans at the moment.

Comment: Your application needed to have an attestation which you did not provide. The ECO caught you out and she already KNOWS you have a beau in the UK. Hence you got a really mild refusal; it's certainly not the end of the world. Work on your attestation and you may need the help of a REAL solicitor.  I'm somewhat doubtful that you actually used an agency (even in Russia).Or if you did, that you revealed your secondary agenda to them.

Comment: I did use an agency. Even though now I doubt of their competence... they were telling me since the beginning that I must have said that I don't know anyone there, which led me to a problem now. Also, will I be most likely banned if in my new visa application I will state that I actually have a friend there?

Comment: You won't be banned if your attestation is crystal perfect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, let me tell you that is was incredibly stupid to lie in the application. Saying so is too late for you now, but perhaps other readers of this site will take notice.

Next, consider what you are trying to do in the long run. It seems to me that you **are** trying to live in the UK fairly regularly, and not just visit. That requires a different visa, with different rules and conditions. Trying to apply for the *wrong* type of visa is going to be a problem because the rules for a visitor visa are made to prevent this.

- For living abroad permanently, ask on [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange.
- As long as the UK is in the EU, your boyfriend benefits from the EU regulations which allow him to bring family members. You might qualify as a family member if you are not married but in a *permanent* relationship. Again, ask Expatriates.
- The UK is leaving the EU and we don't know what the rules will be afterwards, especially with regard for people who came between the declaration of Brexit and the time it goes into effect.

Comment: I used to travel to the UK every third week staying there for 2 weeks. So approximately 2.5 weeks I used to spend in Russia, and then 2- in London. Is it considered as living?

Comment: And thank you for the answer. I would also like to know how it would be possible for me now to apply for a new visa, which type I should choose, if I would be banned if I mention now that I know somebody there and what are the options in general.

Comment: @Alina, you were spending almost as much time in the UK as in Russia. That's obviously too much for a tourist. Ask on Expatriates.

Comment: +1 for the Expats vs TSE  'routing' instructions. :)

Comment: The main problem is that now I can't state anymore that I've had a permanent relationship all this time, therefore I don't see any other option except for making a visitor visa, but through attaching an invitation from my boyfriend. I mean it wouldn't be clear like this I suppose that we've known each other for a long time, or at least it wouldn't be said. I don't know though if this would help. And does it make sense to wait for a few months before making a new application, so that my circumstances could change?

Comment: You and the boyfriend should be in sync on when the "relationship" started. Unlike marriage, that can be a somewhat nebulous concept.